# Select2 jQuery CSS changing, on page render.(laravel 5.7 project)

Tags: laravel, jquery-select2

In my laravel project version 5.7, I have a home_admin page in which I use four select dropdown inputs with some CSS custom, and in my `home.js` I initialize them with the select2 function from select2 jQuery library v.4.0.10 CDNS. So when the page renders, within seconds loading firstly the custom CSS and then changes to select 2 default CSS.

What can I do, so as to have only my CSS?

Comment: In addition, in essence the select2 css overwrite my custom css , but this change is visible within seconds

Comment: It's not really recommended but you can add " !important" to your custom css.
Also make sure that your custom files are order to be loaded last.

Alternative - use may use something like gulp and change the order of files to make sure the custom css & js will be load last